# Countdown Timer until Link Appears

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm trying to make a countdown timer that has a link that appears after 20 mns. This is what I have so far...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{
    countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', 720);
}

function countDown(elID, output, seconds)
{
    document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = (seconds==0) ? output : 'Time until link appears: ' + seconds;
    if(seconds==0) { return; }
    setTimeout("countDown('"+elID+"', '"+output+"', "+(seconds-1)+")", 1000);
}
</script>
```

It works, but here's what I'd like to do. How can I change the interval of 20 mns from appearing as 20:00:00 instead of 720 seconds?

Comment: 72000 seconds is 20 hours, not 20 minutes.

Comment: lol well whatever it is, how can I change the format to display in 20:00:00?

Comment: @Thomas 7200 seconds = 2 hours, you have extra 0

Comment: @Shehabix I do since the post was edited :) Let me try again: FYI, 7200 seconds is 2 hours, not 20 minutes.

Comment: This is not secure, the user can just call your function freely with 0 seconds to get the link instantly OR even better, steal it from your output value. I'd suggest not making the user wait.

Comment: I'm fine with that DJDavid98. I just want the code, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all 7200 Seconds = 120 mins not 20;

Now regarding the 20 mins : XX sec

```
var remMinutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var remSeconds = seconds - (remMinutes * 60);

document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = (seconds==0) ? output : 'Time until link appears: ' + remMinutes + "minutes and "+remSeconds+" seconds";
```

or if you want the output to be MM:SS

then use this :

```
document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = (seconds==0) ? output : 'Time until link appears: ' + remMinutes + ":"+remSeconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shehabix answers your question, but I would like to suggest this rewrite of your code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', 720);
}
function countDown(elID, output, seconds) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elID),
        start = new Date().getTime(), end = start+seconds*1000,
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime(), timeleft = end-now, timeparts;
            if( timeleft < 0) {
                elem.innerHTML = output;
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
            else {
                timeparts = [Math.floor(timeleft/60000),Math.floor(timeleft/1000)%60];
                if( timeparts[1] < 10) timeparts[1] = "0"+timeparts[1];
                elem.innerHTML = "Time left: "+timeparts[0]+":"+timeparts[1];
            }
        },250); // the lower this number, the more accurate the timer. 250 recommended
}
```

This will work much more efficiently, because it uses functions rather than relying on `eval` (which is what passing a string to `setTimeout` does). Additionally, it uses delta timing to calculate the time left - this is because specifying 1000ms isn't accurate. It relies on the code being processed instantly, which it isn't.

Comment: I too was going to suggest a similar rewrite using `setInterval` in my answer. My implementation would be a little different so I'll probably add it to my answer when I get home from work.

Comment: Now is there a way, instead of a link to have a .php file pulled and displayed?

Comment: Absolutely. Make an AJAX call in the `clearInterval` area, and put the response into the target box.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know too much about Javascript only php and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A reminder, you shouldn't rely on this for high security, someone could easily read the source and figure out the link. Even if you obfuscate it, if the browser can decode it so can a determined human.

```
var twentyMins = 20 * 60; // 20 minutes * 60 seconds

window.onload = function() {
    countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', twentyMins);
}

function countDown(elID, output, seconds) {
    var mins,
        secs = seconds,
        pad = function (n) {
            return n > 9 ? n : '0' + n;
        };

    // get the hours by dividing by the number of seconds in an hour
    hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600); //  60 * 60 = 3600
    // get the remaining seconds
    secs %= 3600;
    // likewise, get the number of minutes of by dividing the remaining seconds by 60
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    // again, get the remainder of seconds
    secs %= 60;

    // pad any numbers less than 9 with a leading 0
    secs = pad(secs);
    mins = pad(mins);
    hours = pad(hours);

    document.getElementById(elID).innerHTML = (seconds === 0) ? output : 'Time until link appears: ' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;

    // instead of returning, just don't call setTimout if we are done
    if (seconds !== 0) {
        seconds -= 1;
        // there is no need to pass a string to setTimout, you just pass the function name,
        // followed by the timeout in ms, followed by any params
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000, elID, output, seconds);
    }

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjjnd/3/)

**However** it would be a better idea to re-write it using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. This is because timers are not reliable and [timer delay length is not guaranteed](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). Doing `setTimeout(something, 1000)` might execute `something` a second later, or it might execute `something` at sometime after that. It will probably only be a few ms here and there but over any significant amount of time it will add up.

Even something simple like [an `alert` box will stop your `setTimeout` based countdown](http://jsfiddle.net/jjjnd/4/)! The below code updates the counter every half second by recalculating seconds left every time it runs. We could still do this with `setTimeout`, but `setInterval` is better suited for this job. If the browser gets bogged down for some reason `setInterval` will just drop some executions instead of trying to play catch-up. That's fine since it recalculates the time left every time it runs. This also means if an `alert` pops up, it won't matter either.

Another good reason to not count on a sequence of `setTimeout`s to decrement the counter each time it runs is that in our modern world of tabbed browsers background tabs often have their [timer resolution lowered](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/09/19/script-yielding-with-setimmediate/), this can also happen due to [laptop power managment](https://www.belshe.com/2010/06/04/chrome-cranking-up-the-clock/). Usually this means taking the minimum resolution from something like 4ms up to 15ms so it shouldn't bother us in this situation, but it is something you need to know about when working with timers.

```
var twentyMins = 20 * 60; // 20 minutes * 60 seconds

window.onload = function() {
    countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', twentyMins);
}

function countDown(elID, output, seconds) {
    "use strict";
    var timer, // timer will hold a reference to the id of our interval
        // store a reference to the element so we don't have to keep looking it up
        el = document.getElementById(elID),
        getTime = function () {
            // get the current time in ms since Unix epoch
            return (new Date()).getTime();
        },
        // we will be done counting down when we are
        // `seconds` seconds from the current time
        finishAt = getTime() + (seconds * 1000),
        pad = function (n) {
            return n > 9 ? n : '0' + n;
        },
        lastCount = -1,
        update = function () {
            var hours,
                now = getTime(),
                mins,
                // the seconds remaining is the finish time
                // minus the current time divided by 1000ms
                secs = Math.floor((finishAt - now) / 1000);


            // Since we might be running this update function more than once
            // a second, check to see if the number of seconds has changed since
            // our last run. If it hasn't there is no need to do any more calculations
            // nor update the DOM.
            if (lastCount !== secs) {

                lastCount = secs;

                // you need to make sure the current time is equal to OR GREATER THEN the finish time
                // because the interval could have actually fired sometime (shortly)
                // after the time stored in finishAt
                if (now >= finishAt) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    el.innerHTML =  output;
                } else {
                    // get the hours by dividing by the number of seconds in an hour
                    hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600); //  60 * 60 = 3600
                    // get the remaining seconds
                    secs %= 3600;

                    // likewise, get the number of minutes of by dividing the remaining seconds by 60
                    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);

                    // again, get the remainder of seconds
                    secs %= 60;
                    secs = Math.floor(secs);

                    // pad any numbers less than 9 with a leading 0
                    secs = pad(secs);
                    mins = pad(mins);
                    hours = pad(hours);

                    el.innerHTML = 'Time until link appears: ' + hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
                }
            }
        };

    // display the counter right away
    update();

    // start the timer, updating twice a second to try and avoid
    // having the counter seem to skip numbers
    timer = setInterval(update, 499);
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjjnd/7/)

You may have noticed that in both of the solutions I proposed, I used the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_.28Modulus.29) when calculating the different time components. I did this because using the [remainder operator is faster](http://jsperf.com/multiply-subtract-vs-remainder) than multiplying to get the minutes as seconds and then subtracting. You may have also noticed that my code uses the strict equality/inequality [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`. Not only will this coding style make [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) [hurt your feelings](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) less, it is again slightly faster.

In the second, better solution the variable `lastCount` stores the total number of seconds left from the previous execution. Since the code will be running more than once a second it is useful to see if the result has changed since last time. If it hasn't we don't have to do anymore work. We don't have to calculate minutes and more importantly we don't have to touch the DOM, because [DOM access is slow](http://www.phpied.com/dom-access-optimization/).

Comment: Now is there a way, instead of a link to have a .php file pulled and displayed?

Comment: What do you mean by "pulled"? Do you mean displayed inside the same page or would just redirecting to it work? Redirecting is easy, just pass the URL into the function instead of the link HTML you currently are; then you just have to change `el.innerHTML = output;` to `window.location = output;`. If you want to display it inside the same page it gets more complicated, like Kolink said you would need to use Ajax to grab it. If you are doing something that complex I would suggest using a DOM/Ajax library like jQuery. That would make doing the Ajax call much easier and more headache free.